# Why would the for loop be looping through an array that has a length of 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

In the following program, one of two functions is called - the functions either add (w3AddClass) or remove (w3RemoveClass) div items according to whether the c value matches a class attribute in any given div. In both functions there is a for loop. My question is about the for loop - in both functions the for loop loops through an array (arr2) whose length is just 1 (i.e. "show"). Shouldn't it instead loop through the longer array (arr1)?

```js
filterSelection("cars")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");

  if (c == "all") c = " ";

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");

    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1)
      w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, ** name ** ) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;

  arr1 = element.className.split(" "); **
  arr2 = name.split(" "); **

  for (i = 0; i < ** arr2.length ** ; i++) {

    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className = element.className + " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  //etc...
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does those `**` in the code are a typo or something? But anyway, I did not understand your question

Comment: The double * was supposed to make the content between the double asterisks bold, just to isolate that part of the code b/c that's the part of the code that I'm trying to get a clarification on..

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it instead loop through the longer array (arr1)?

No it doesn't. `arr1` is just needed for check whether the element has given class or not.

For example, second paramter of `w3AddClass` could be a space separated string. `w3AddClass(e, "a b c")` will add `a`, `b` and `c` class to the element.

Comment: Is the code checking whether any of the elements that include the class name matching "c"...also have the class "show", and if any of these div's have the c, but not the "show", add "show"! Do I have that right?

Comment: @StanislavMatveyevich Not any of the elements but just given element, and add every class that in the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - so the for loop is looping through the passed classes, which in this case is one single class "show".. So if I understand you correctly - the loop will only run once for every given div?

Comment: Got it. Thanks, dude!